# Multer-sftp trying to upload file into locale instead of remote server

Tags: node.js, express, file-upload, sftp, multer

I have the following code:

```js
const multer = require('multer');
const sftpStorage = require('multer-sftp');

const path = require('path');

const storage = sftpStorage({
    sftp: {
        host: '**.***.***.***',
        port: 22,
        username: 'root',
        password: '****',
    },
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, '/var/www/html/imagenes_identifica');
    },
    filename: function (_req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
})

const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('file');

module.exports = upload;
```

My plan is to update a file using multer sftp to my remote server, but, the problem is that (I think) multer is trying to upload the file to locale computer instead of the remote server.

I'm using it on my request as the following:

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const arbolService = require('../services/arbolService');
const upload = require('../middlewares/fileUpload');

router.post('/setMarker', upload, (req, res, next) => {
    arbolService.setArbolMarker(req, res);
});
```

And receiving this error:

```
{
  error: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\var\www\html\imagenes_identifica\1659453834044.jpg'] {
    errno: -4058,
    code: 'ENOENT',
    syscall: 'open',
    path: 'C:\\var\\www\\html\\imagenes_identifica\\1659453834044.jpg'
  }
}
```

This path does exist on my server, as I am seeing it on FileZilla:
[image: FileZilla]

What am I doing wrong?